# Why is argparse not parsing my boolean flag correctly?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the argparse module to make my Python program accept flexible command-line arguments. I want to pass a simple boolean flag, and  saying `True` or `False` to execute the appropriate branch in my code.

Consider the following.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test.py',formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-boolflag', type=bool, default=True)
parser.add_argument('-intflag' , type=int, default=3)
args = parser.parse_args()

boolflag = args.boolflag
intflag  = args.intflag


print ("Bool Flag is ", boolflag)
print ("Int Flag is ",  intflag)
```

When I tried to execute it with `python scrap.py -boolflag False -intflag 314` I got the result

```
Bool Flag is  True
Int Flag is  314
```

Why is this?!! The intflag seems to be parsed correctly, yet the boolean flag is invariably parsed as `True` even if I mention explicitly in the command-line arguments that I want it to be `False`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are trying to turn the string `"False"` into a boolean:

```
>>> bool("False")
True
```

That won't work because the string `"False"` is a non-empty value. *All* non-empty strings have a `True` boolean value.

Use a [`store_false` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) instead:

```
parser.add_argument('--disable-feature', dest='feature', 
                    action='store_false')
```

Now when you use that switch, `False` is stored, otherwise the default is `True` (set by `action='store_false'`).