# Argparse optional boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to get the following behaviour:

- `python test.py`  ⟹ store `foo=False`
- `python test.py --foo` ⟹ store `foo=True`
- `python test.py --foo bool` ⟹ store `foo=bool`

It works when I use

```py
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default=False, const=True)
```

However, it breaks if I add `type=bool`, trying to enforce casting to boolean. In this case

```sh
python test.py --foo False
```

Actually ends up storing `foo=True`. What's going on??

Comment: Also see [Why is argparse not parsing my boolean flag correctly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41655897)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Are you *sure* you need that pattern? `--foo` and `--foo <value>`, together, for a boolean switch, is not a common pattern to use.

As for your issue, remember that the command line value is a *string* and, `type=bool` means that you want `bool(entered-string-value)` to be applied. For `--foo False` that means `bool("False")`, producing `True`; all non-empty strings are true! See [Why is argparse not parsing my boolean flag correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655897/why-is-argparse-not-parsing-my-boolean-flag-correctly) as well.

Instead of supporting `--foo` / `--foo <string value>`, I would *strongly* recommend you use `--foo` to mean `True`, drop the argument value, and instead add a `--no-foo` option to explicitly set `False`:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', default=False, action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--no-foo', dest='foo', action='store_false')
```

The `dest='foo'` addition on the `--no-foo` switch ensures that the `False` value it stores (via `store_false`) ends up on the same `args.foo` attribute.

As of Python 3.9, you can also use the `argparse.BooleanOptionalAction` action class:

```
parser.add_argument("--foo", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction)
```

and it'll have the same effect, handling `--foo` and `--no-foo` to set and clear the flag.

You'd only need a `--foo / --no-foo` combination if you have some other configuration mechanism that would set `foo` to `True` and you needed to override this again with a command-line switch. `--no-<option>` is a widely adopted standard to invert a boolean command-line switch.

If you *don't* have a specific need for a `--no-foo` inverted switch (since just *omitting* `--foo` would already mean 'false'), then just stick with the `action='store_true'` option. This keeps your command line simple and clear!

However, if your use case or other constraints specifically require that your command line *must* have some king of `--foo (true|false|0|1)` support, then add your own converter:

```
def str_to_bool(value):
    if isinstance(value, bool):
        return value
    if value.lower() in {'false', 'f', '0', 'no', 'n'}:
        return False
    elif value.lower() in {'true', 't', '1', 'yes', 'y'}:
        return True
    raise ValueError(f'{value} is not a valid boolean value')

parser.add_argument('--foo', type=str_to_bool, nargs='?', const=True, default=False)
```

- the `const` value is used for `nargs='?'` arguments where the argument value is omitted. Here that sets `foo=True` when `--foo` is used.
- `default=False` is used when the switch is not used at all.
- `type=str_to_bool` is used to handle the `--foo <value>` case.

Demo:

```
$ cat so52403065.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()

def str_to_bool(value):
    if value.lower() in {'false', 'f', '0', 'no', 'n'}:
        return False
    elif value.lower() in {'true', 't', '1', 'yes', 'y'}:
        return True
    raise ValueError(f'{value} is not a valid boolean value')

parser.add_argument('--foo', type=str_to_bool, nargs='?', const=True, default=False)

print(parser.parse_args())
$ python so52403065.py
Namespace(foo=False)
$ python so52403065.py --foo
Namespace(foo=True)
$ python so52403065.py --foo True
Namespace(foo=True)
$ python so52403065.py --foo no
Namespace(foo=False)
$ python so52403065.py --foo arrbuggrhellno
usage: so52403065.py [-h] [--foo [FOO]]
so52403065.py: error: argument --foo: invalid str_to_bool value: 'arrbuggrhellno'
```

Comment: So the reason I want this is because the what I am writing is a builder file that writes a number of bash scripts and submits them to a SLURM workload manager.  The optional parameters I submit get subjected to some preprocessing steps and then a derived set of parameters get appended to the python call inside the SLURM script.

Now, the easiest way I found to implement this is to have a  dictionary of parameters that I want to pass to the SLURM script and append all key-value pairs.

Now with your suggestion I would have to check whether or not a flag was manually set or not.

Comment: @Hyperplane: you could accept a JSON-encoded config string perhaps? Then if `args.json_config` is the decoded JSON object then all you have to do is use `args = parser.parse_args()` and `args.__dict__.update(args.json_config)`

Comment: @Hyperplane: `parser.add_argument('--json-config', type=json.loads)` should be enough to define such a switch.

Comment: That sounds like a really nice solution. At the moment using a `type=string2bool` seems sufficient, but I will keep this idea in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: for the --no-<flag> pattern argparse introduced the BooleanOptionalAction https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: @pseyfert: gotta love the lack of proper documentation on that addition, or even a 'added in' entry! So it is [new in 3.9](https://bugs.python.org/issue8538).

Answer (score 29):

You should use the [`action='store_true'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) parameter instead for Boolean arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
```

So that the absence of the `--foo` option:

```
python test.py
```

would result in a `False` value for the `foo` argument, and the presence of the `--foo` option:

```
python test.py --foo
```

would result in a `True` value for the `foo` argument.

Comment: But that wouldn't allow for `--foo bool`.

Comment: It's not needed. I've updated my answer with better explanations.

Comment: Sure, but there *are* use-cases for specifying *disable the foo option*, specifically in a 'merged configuration from multiple sources including the command line' scenario. `--no-foo` is the usual choice there.

Comment: @blhsing case in point: I came here because I wanted to know how to have both `--foo` and `--foo stuff` using argparse.